# Importação de arquivo no SSIS com colunas em posições diferentes cada dia

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssis

Estou com a seguinte situação: faço uma importação Flat File (Arquivo Simples) de um arquivo *.CSV para uma tabela no banco. Utilizando SSIS no Visual Studio. Porém, cada dia o arquivo que recebo tem a ordem das colunas alterada. Assim, o campo de "e-mail", por exemplo, pode acabar recebendo a informação do "telefone".
Como faço para que independente da ordem que vier, a importação identifique as colunas corretas?

```
Exemplo: 
Ordem das colunas no Dia 01: Email, Nome, Telefone
Ordem das colunas no Dia 02: Telefone, Email, Nome
```

Comment: O arquivo texto (formato CSV) possui linha inicial com os cabeçalhos que identificam o conteúdo de cada coluna?

Comment: Sim. A primeira linha é o cabeçalho.

Answer (score 0):

Caso a ordem das colunas mude, o SSIS mantém a estrutura da informação associada a essa coluna. Verifique nas opções avançadas da Source do Flat File

Exemplo Dia 01:

`Col1, Col2, Col3
   A     B     C
  AA    BB    CC`

Exemplo Dia 02:

`Col2, Col1, Col3
   B     A     C
  BB    AA    CC`

Depois terá de mapear dinamicamente as colunas através de uma Script Task porque o SSIS não tem algo pré-definido para esse mapeamento dinamico.

Comment: O que quer dizer com "mapear dinamicamente"? Poderia ser pouquinho mais leigo? Estou começando na ferramenta.

Comment: Fiz um teste jogando de um *.CSV para um *.TXT. O arquivo de texto recebe o conteúdo da coluna de mesmo nome lida no CSV. Daí entendi que o problema está no source flat file. Olhando a opções de avançado, não há muita coisa, não encontrei algo que sugere "coluna dinâmica". `Exemplo do campo 'Nome': Delimitador de Coluna é ';' e  tipo é cadeia de caracteres [DT_WSTR] . Opção TextQualified=True. ColumnType=Delimitado`. Que opção particular eu deveria procurar? @TiagoMeireles

Comment: @CatharinaOliveira o que quis dizer com mapeamento dinâmico foi, através de uma script task, desenvolver um script que coloque os valores da coluna que diz "Nome" na coluna de destino "Nome" e por aí adiante. Assim, independentemente da ordem das colunas, conseguirá ter sempre a informação correta a ser colocada no sitio correto.

Ou seja, você colocou um .CSV como Source e um .TXT como destination certo? E independentemente da ordem, a informação aparece correta? A informação de nome, é enviada para a coluna Nome, independentemente da ordem?

Comment: Oi @TiagoMeireles. Entendi, mas para isso ele tem que pelo menos ler corretamente. E não fica correto. Se eu trocar a coluna de lugar, o seu conteúdo vai para o local errado. Ele não acompanha aquele seu exemplo acima.

Comment: @CatharinaOliveira Olá, já entendi. Existe um plugin para o SSIS que é o CozyRoc Data Flow Task Plus (É gratuito!) que suporta o mapeamento que falei de colunas dinâmicas. Caso não consiga com esse plugin terá de ser através de uma script task :\

Comment: Aaa tá certo Tiago. Muito obrigada!! Testarei. Abraço!